# .animate fails randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having some problems making my animation work and it stops at random times on my ipad

so I have this html

```
<body>


<div class="touchslider-prev  sliderButtons" style="display: block;">back</div>
<div class="touchslider-next  sliderButtons" style="display: block;">next</div>

<section id="mainContent" style="width: 950px; overflow:hidden">

    <div id="pageHolder" style="float: left; left: 0;  position: relative; width: 6000px;">


         <div class="pageSize activeSlide" id="page1" style="width: 950px; float: left;  position: relative; height:500px; background-color:#F00">

           blah

         </div>  


          <div class="pageSize " id="page" style="width: 950px;  float: left;  position: relative; height:500px; background-color:#FF0">

           blah 2

         </div>          


    </div>


</section>

</body>
```

---

and this javascript

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function clickHandlerPrev(event) {

    // If event isn't already marked as handled, handle it
    if(event.handled !== true) {

        // Kill event handler, preventing any more clicks
        jQuery(window).off("swipeBackward", clickHandlerPrev);
    jQuery(window).off("swipeForward", clickHandlerNext);

        // Do your stuff here
        pageSize = jQuery(".mainHeader").width();
        slide("back", pageSize);

        // Mark event as handled
        event.handled = true;
    } 

    return false;
}

function clickHandlerNext(event) {

    // If event isn't already marked as handled, handle it

    if(event.handled !== true) {

        // Kill event handler, preventing any more clicks
        jQuery(window).off("swipeBackward", clickHandlerPrev);
    jQuery(window).off("swipeForward", clickHandlerNext);

        // Do your stuff here
        pageSize = jQuery(".mainHeader").width();
        slide("forward", pageSize);

        // Mark event as handled
        event.handled = true;
    }
    return false;
}



function slide(data, pageSize) {


    if (!pageSize) {
    pageSize = 950;
    }

    var left = calcLeft(data, pageSize);




        jQuery('#pageHolder').animate({
            left: left

          }, 400, function() {
            console.log("animation started");
            jQuery(window).on("swipeBackward", clickHandlerPrev);
    jQuery(window).on("swipeForward", clickHandlerNext);
            console.log("animation complete");

        });



}

function calcLeft(action, pageSize){

    var left;
    var currentPos = currentPosition();


    if (action == "back") {
console.log(pageSize);

        if (currentPos == "0") {
            left = -pageSize * 1;
        } else {

            left = currentPos + pageSize ;

        }

    } else if (action == "forward") {


        if (currentPos == -pageSize * 1) {
            left = 0;
        } else {        
            left = currentPos - pageSize ;

        }

    }

    return left;

}

function currentPosition() {

    var currentPosition = parseInt(jQuery("#pageHolder").css("left"), 10);
    return currentPosition;
}






jQuery(document).ready(function () {

jQuery(".touchslider-prev").click( function() { 

    jQuery(window).trigger('swipeForward');

});

jQuery(".touchslider-next").click( function() { 

    jQuery(window).trigger('swipeBackward');

});


jQuery(window).on('swipeForward', clickHandlerNext );
jQuery(window).on('swipeBackward', clickHandlerPrev );


console.log("here");
var maxTime = 1000,
    // allow movement if < 1000 ms (1 sec)
    maxDistance = 50,
    // swipe movement of 50 pixels triggers the swipe
    target = jQuery('.pageSize'),
    startX = 0,
    startTime = 0,
    touch = "ontouchend" in document,
    startEvent = (touch) ? 'touchstart' : 'mousedown',
    moveEvent = (touch) ? 'touchmove' : 'mousemove',
    endEvent = (touch) ? 'touchend' : 'mouseup';

target.bind(startEvent, function(e) {
    // prevent image drag (Firefox)
    // e.preventDefault();
    startTime = e.timeStamp;
    startX = e.originalEvent.touches ? e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX : e.pageX;
}).bind(endEvent, function(e) {
    startTime = 0;
    startX = 0;
}).bind(moveEvent, function(e) {
    // e.preventDefault();
    var currentX = e.originalEvent.touches ? e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX : e.pageX,
        currentDistance = (startX === 0) ? 0 : Math.abs(currentX - startX),
        // allow if movement < 1 sec
        currentTime = e.timeStamp;
    if (startTime !== 0 && currentTime - startTime < maxTime && currentDistance > maxDistance) {
        if (currentX < startX) {
            // swipe left code here

           console.log("page forward trigger");
           jQuery(window).trigger('swipeForward');

        }
        if (currentX > startX) {
            // swipe right code here
             console.log("page back trigger");
           //slide("back", pageSize);
            jQuery(window).trigger('swipeBackward');
        }
        startTime = 0;
        startX = 0;
    }
});


});


</script>
```

---

if you open this on say an ipad the idea is you can swipe the main colour panel. this will work sometimes and sometimes not and I am really struggling to find out why

can anyone help?

the slide stops periodically but if the users just uses the back/next button it always works, there doesn't seem to be an issue with the slide code though as it just triggers an event?

i have placed the code here

http://demo.stg.brightonconsulting.net.au/templates/tests/ipadSlider/

Comment: It works fine on my PC touch screen, isn't the animation canceled because the page is being scrolled while swiping the slider?

Comment: yes it works on the computer - not the ipad - the idea is that the swipe triggers an event that event then runs the slide - how could i get around this?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me like you install event handlers for both swipeForward and swipeBackward, but then you only deinstall the one that fires.  The next time, you install both event handlers again, thus some of them will pile up and be installed more than once which will certainly mess with your animation when one fires that is installed more than once.  If you're going to deinstall when one fires, then you need to deinstall both, not just the one that fired.  Same issue with the click handlers.

In addition, in `calcLeft()`, the variable `left` should be declared as a local variable.  Also, what is `jQuery.when(promise)` doing when `promise` is an integer?  You're supposed to pass a deferred object to `jQuery.when()`.

Comment: i have changed the question and the uploaded code to have left declared and i have removed the promise.

Comment: @Dan - did you fix the issue about multiple event handlers getting installed?  That's the main issue I see.

Comment: i have also updated it so there are two handlers. i have pushed the code. is that what you meant?

Comment: @Dan - No, the problem is not fixed.  I think maybe you don't understand it yet.  In the `slide()` function, you install four event handlers.  When one of those event handlers fires, it deinstalls only itself, leaving the other three event handlers in place and then calls `slide()` again.  Now, you have 7 event handlers installed.  Three of the four objects have double event handlers.  Now, one of those three events fires and the event handler gets called twice.  When it gets called twice, the animation that the first once just started gets interrupted by the second event handler.

Comment: hi, sorry I have updated it again. is that what you mean? - this still doesnt make it work consistently though

Comment: ok. i did have some bad names in there. was using click instead of swipeBackward when dealing with event. but this still fails. the events seem to be correct now.

Comment: can you help? I am a bit stuck now.